# NSBundle pathForResource returns nil?

Tags: ios, nsbundle

I'm working on an iOS project that other developers created and I'm having problems running this app. Now, at some point I have the following code, which returns `nil` and there's where more problems are coming:

```
NSString *staticLibraryBundlePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"SRVRTrackingResources" ofType:@"bundle"];
```

I'm not sure what is this actually looking for, I will post a structure of the project's folders:

[image]

I'm not sure what file is it looking for, the `.plist` one?

Any thoughts?

Comment: check this https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/pathForResource:ofType:

Answer (score 3):

**SRVRTrackingResources**  is of folder type ;is not a bundle. that's why it return nil.

> **Return Value**
>   *The full pathname for the resource file or **nil** if the file could not be located. This method also returns nil if the bundle specified by the bundlePath parameter does not exist or is not a readable directory.*

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:filename ofType:@"plist"];
```

for more check the [Link](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000214-pathForResource_ofType_inDirectory_)